# Issues with variable scope I am sure

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am basically having an issue with variable scope. Knowing multiple programming languages, I just can't wrap my head around obj-c sometimes.

In my webviewcontroller class I have a variable that I call using self.var

I also have some delegate methods that reference a modified UIAlertView. Why can't I reference this self.var in those methods without the entire app crashing?

I have tried everything and its been a few days and now I need help!

Thanks!

Edit:

Here is the code webviewcontroller.h

```
    #import "SBTableAlert.h"

    @interface WebViewController : UIViewController <SBTableAlertDelegate, SBTableAlertDataSource>{
            NSMutableArray *bookmarks;
    }
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *bookmarks;
```

here is the .m (yes I have an @synthesize for bookmarks), this is in view did load

```
    NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [tmpDict objectForKey:@"myKey"];
    self.bookmarks = tmpArray;
    [tmpDict release];
    [tmpArray release];

    SBTableAlert *bookmarkAlert;

    bookmarkAlert = [[SBTableAlert alloc] initWithTitle:@"Jump to:" cancelButtonTitle:@"Back" messageFormat:nil];
    [bookmarkAlert.view setTag:1];
    [bookmarkAlert setDelegate:self];
    [bookmarkAlert setDataSource:self];

NSString *settingsicon = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"gear" ofType:@"png"];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:settingsicon] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:bookmarkAlert action:@selector(show)];
```

and later I try to call self.bookmarks

```
    - (NSInteger)tableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
            return [self.bookmarks count];
    }
```

The error I get at the self.bookmarks count is NSInvalidArgumentException

Comment: What kind of crash are you getting? Did you declare the property as retain or assign?

Comment: do you mean 'variable lifetime'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to answer without seeing some of your code.

Like Farmer_Joe asked, how are you defining the property?  Something like:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyVar *var;
```

is different from

```
@property MyVar *var;
```

How are you assigning to the var?

```
var = value;
```

won't kick in the retain, but this would (if the property is defined as "retain"):

```
self.var = value
```

Edit: based on the new code you posted, it looks like you're over-releasing tmpArray.  Remove this line:

```
[tmpArray release];
```

You shouldn't have to release tmpArray, because this line doesn't retain it:

```
NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [tmpDict objectForKey:@"myKey"];
```

Comment: I am using. 
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyVar *var;
self.var = value

Comment: OMG It worked!!! I have been on this problem since Monday. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

I didn't know there was such a thing as over releasing. 

Scumbag programmer: Tries to manage memory, over releases var!

Comment: Reddit much? :p  If you haven't already, read the memory management guide. It should make things more clear.  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html

Comment: haha thanks :P made this for you: http://www.reddit.com/r/iPhoneDev/comments/kwo12/scumbag_ios_programmer_cant_manage_memory/

Comment: also, because of reddit, the up and down arrows here confuse the heck out of me.

Answer (score 0):

By variable I assume you mean ivar (instance variable).  Did you create a `@property` for the ivar and if so please provide the code.  Did you provide a `@synthesize` statement for the ivar?

If not you probably need to provide them.

`self.var = x;` calls the var's setter the same as: `[var setVar:x];`

Assuming that the variable is designed to be accesses from outside the class add a @property statement to the .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) ClassName *var;
```

in the associated .m file add:

```
@synthesize var;
```

In the .m file method dealloc add:

```
[var release];
```

The all used should access var as:
In the defining class: `self.var`
In other classes referencing by the `instantiatedVariable.var`

Consider studying Apple's [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW1), it will save a lot of time and frustration.

Comment: I did both. Do I need to synthesize it in the included class as well?

Comment: I edited with code. Also what is instantiatedVariable.var? Oh god I am starting to sound like a total newbie!

Comment: You should not release tmpArray, it was not return retained.  It will save you a lot of time to read Apple's memory usage guide.  Also if you use ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) then you never use retain, release or autorelease.

Comment: ARC adds all the referencing counting behind the scenes, you never write or see retain, release or autorelease.  ARC is the future. While ARC is not under NDA it does require Xcode 4.2 which is only available to developers and is under NDA.  Assuming you have signed up for the $99 developer program grab Xcode 4.2 from the Beta section.

Answer (score 0):

I see the following issues:

- Don't do this: `[tmpArray release]`. You don't own the reference to tmpArray, it's auto-released.
- Do you own the reference for `tmpDict`? -- also, that is an awful var name ;)
- Can you confirm `[tmpDict objectForKey:@"myKey"]` returns an array?